# from csv to array with end of line chars

Tags: php, csv

To parse CSV files in php im using this function:

```
private function _csvToArray($url, $delimiter=',')
{
    $csvData = file_get_contents($url);
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
    $array = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $array[] = str_getcsv($line, $delimiter);
    }

    return $array;
}
```

The problem here is Im using EOL to determine where a line ends, if the CSV file have any field with any end of line chars im getting errors.

Example:

```
Product_Name, "Description"
Product_Name, "Description"
Product_Name, "Description"
Product_Name, "Description"
```

This works ok, but if I have something like this:

```
Product_Name, "Description_line_1
Description_line_2"
Product_Name, "Description_line_1
Description_line_2"
Product_Name, "Description_line_1
Description_line_2"
```

The script will fail, is there any way I can improve the script in order to consider this or is better to use a regular expression to fix first the CSV before calling the sript?

Comment: using php_eol in your explode is unreliable. that's the eol constant for YOUR system. if the remote system is using a different eol char, you'll be exploding on the wrong thing. you'd probably be better off just fetching the file, writing it to disk, and then use the normal fgetcsv() on it.

Comment: As far as my understanding is concerned, In CSV file the rows are separated by a new line while the columns are separated by a comma.Correct your csv format

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (havent properly tested the code):

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($url), ',', '"');
```

I had an old code lying around which fixed this once for me... But remember... it's from way way back;

```
$url = 'file.csv';
$csv = array();
$csvContents = file_get_contents($url);

$lines = explode('"'."\n", trim($csvContents));
foreach($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {
    $csv[$lineNumber] = array();
    $fields = explode(',', $line);
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $csv[$lineNumber][] = ltrim(rtrim($field, '"'), '"');
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail the same way.

Comment: @MIvanIsten working code supplied... (old, old code from a foregone era)

Comment: Yes, thats a workaround. But to work, the last field in row must be between `"`-s

Comment: Yeah... And if I deduct correctly, there can be no comma's enclosed in between the double-quotes... But as I said; old code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save writing to a temporary file yourself you can use the memory stream.

```
private function _csvToArray($url, $delimiter=',')
{
    $fp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    fwrite($fp, file_get_contents($url));

    fseek($fp, 0);

    $array = array();

    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp, 0, $delimiter)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgetcsv` can handle EOL in fields if the field data is between enclosure characters.

```
private function _csvToArray($url, $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"')
{
    $handle = fopen($url, 'r');
    $array = array();

    while($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter, $enclosure))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }

    fclose($handle);
    return $array;
}
```